# Asterisk (*) in Android XML attributes

Tags: android, xml

Can anyone explain the asterisk means in Android XML attributes?

```
<style name="DocumentsTheme" parent="@style/DialogWhenReallyLarge">
    <item name="android:actionBarTheme">@*android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="*android:windowFixedWidthMajor">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The * allows you to access private resources. Private resources are private for a reason as their name could change in the future as part of a firmware or skin update.

It's not a good idea to use these resources unless you're working in an environment where you know these resources won't change and break your app in the future.

In your example, the private resources are being referenced by a system app which is where you'll most commonly see this * referencing used.

```
@android:id refers to the public system member called "id"
@id refers to one that you've created
@+id says to create one called "id" (and what to set it to)
@*android:id refers to a private system member
```