# Significance of * in Android style attribute naming convention for private attributes

Tags: android, android-styles

***Introduction:*** I was trying to create a full `DialogFragment`. As I can remember there were `android:windowMinWidthMajor` and `android:windowMinWidthMinor` and they are public attributes. But there were no public attributes for **height**. Indeed there are `android:windowFixedHeightMajor` and `android:windowFixedHeightMinor`, but they are private and AAPT2 throws `AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/windowFixedHeightMinor' is private.`


***Question:*** Then I found a solution, prefix the attribute name with *****. Something like `<item name=*android:windowFixedHeightMinor">80%</item>` and it worked. But the behaviour is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation. Since search query contains ***** character and search engines treat ***** as a wildcard character. A web search didn't provide a single useful result. It will be really helpful if someone can explain a bit more about such naming prefix behaviour.

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30200875/12855428

Comment: @LuizFernandodeMoura Thanks alot for the comment and it solves the query.